# Job error on the Talend Management Console (Cloud) : Broken pipe (Write failed) while writing from S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, talend

I've been getting the same error on my Talend Cloud Job.
It's a job that is trying to insert 400k - 500k rows (at the moment, could be less in the next months or could be more)

We are using a Redshift db and to insert those rows into the db we've been using tDBOutputBulkExec since it's the most performant component to insert data

But for this job only we're getting the same error :

```
tDBBulkExec_1 An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend
```

also with

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.deliver(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:345)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.RedshiftStream.flush(RedshiftStream.java:605)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendFlush(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1173)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:365)
    ... 17 more
```

I've tried to replace the tDBOutputBulkExec with a
tFileOutputDelimited -> tFileArchive -> tS3Put -> tDBBulkExec

Only to be able to use the "multipart upload" option in the tS3Put (not availabe in other components).
As I don't know really well those component I've choosed a partition size of 10mo

I don't know what cause this problem. Picture attached

[image: My talend job]

Comment: Do the components as configured operate successfully IF run on only a few rows?  (Is this a configuration issue or data size issue?)

Comment: I've seen this type of error when networks get in the way.  Incorrect MTU or network devices with connection timeouts.  Any chance there are possible issues with the networking between talend and RS?

Comment: @BillWeiner The job is running if there is less rows. It worked with 8500 rows but as soon as I want to use the full size of the job there's an error

Comment: About the network @BillWeiner what should I ask to the team managing this ? There could be some limitations yes, but I have no idea what's happening between S3 and RedShift, I only manage the source, the talend job and then the export to redshift. The AWS Bucket is just a mean that I have no control over. Any help appreciated

Comment: There are 2 possible network configuration issues that can cause this loss of connection that I know of.  MTU is the max packet size that information will be transmitted over the network.  MTU needs to be no more than 1500 on the talend server or large commands to Redshift will be truncated and cause hangs.  Also every router between talend and RS can have a "connection idle time" timeout configured.  This closes connections that have no traffic on them for some period of time (I've seen 30min).  AWS routers don't have this configured but non-AWS ones may.

Comment: Non-network related timeouts can happen too.  RS has statement timeout rules that can be set but I'd expect these to generate a 'connection reset by peer' type of error message, not a hang.